# Adding to array in array (building groups of data)

Tags: php, arrays, reference

In PHP I'm loop through results from the database, and I want to group the results into sections, so I have the following code...

```
$query = $db->prepare('select groupid, myval1, myval2 from mytable');
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($groupid, $myval1, $myval2);
$groups = [];
$currentgroup = null;
while ($query->fetch()) {
  if ($currentgroup == null || $currentgroup["groupid"] != $groupid) {
    $currentgroup = ["groupid" => $groupid, "values" => []];
    $groups[] = $currentgroup;
  }
  $currentgroup["values"][] = ["myval1" => $myval1, "myval2" => $myval2];
}
$query->close();
```

This results in the `$groups` array containing an individual item for each specific group, but the `values` array remains empty...

```
$groups = [
  ["groupid" = 1, "values" = []],
  ["groupid" = 2, "values" = []],
  ["groupid" = 3, "values" = []]
]
```

When I debug through the loop, I can see that `$currentgroup["values"]` **is** populating correctly, but it appears that even though `$currentgroup` has been added to `$groups`, the values are not being populates.  This suggests to me that different arrays are being used, but I can't see how to fix it... I guess references are required, but I'm struggling to work out how.

How do I fix the above code to result in...

```
$groups = [
  ["groupid" = 1, "values" = [
    ["myval1" = 1, "myval2" = 2],
    ["myval1" = 3, "myval2" = 4]
  ],
  ["groupid" = 2, "values" = [
    ["myval1" = 5, "myval2" = 6],
    ["myval1" = 7, "myval2" = 8],
    ["myval1" = 9, "myval2" = 10]
  ],
  ["groupid" = 3, "values" = []]
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you indexed your `$groups` array by the `groupid`, then you can use this to add the values to the correct grouping.  So inside your loop becomes...

```
if ( !isset($groups[$groupid]) ) {
    $groups[$groupid] = ["groupid" => $groupid, "values" => []];
}
$groups[$groupid]["values"][] = ["myval1" => $myval1, "myval2" => $myval2];
```

You may want to remove these group numbers at the end, just use `array_values()` to do this...

```
$groups = array_values($groups);
```

Comment: Was just writing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Aren't you a week early?!

Comment: Easter egg conversation aside (yes, you're a week early!) ;-) That's excellent.  I was fixated on not having to lookup the group on each iteration of the loop, but it makes perfect sense.  Thank you :-)